# Cannot find Qt QML SpinBox minimumValue using QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Tags: qt, qml

I got this piece of code:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("spinbox trouble")

    SpinBox{
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        value: 5
        minimumValue: 1
        maximumValue: 10
    }
}
```

Everything is fine. Now I want to use `SwipeView`. To use it I need use `QtQuick.Controls 2.1`. But when I use version 2.1, I cannot find *[minimum/maximum]Value* in SpinBox.

**Questions**:
1. What is reason to drop this properties in `QtQuick.Controls 2.1`?
2. Is there any way to use both `SwipeView` and `SpinBox` with *[minimum/maximum]Value* property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-spinbox.html#from-prop) I'd say you can use the `from` and `to` properties instead of `minimumValue` and `maximumValue`!?